# Recurrence Problem involving multiple dependencies.

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have 3 equations :-

1. $r_n=r_{n-1}+5m_{n-1}$
2. $m_n = r_{n-1} + 3m_{n-1}$
3. $p_n = 5m_{n-1}$

The initial values of the sequences are

$$r_0=3, m_0=1, p_0=0$$

How can I get the formula to get the n<sup>th</sup> term of the series without the recurrence?

A ready-made  will be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Define the matrix $$M = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 5 & 0 \\ 1 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 5 & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$
Then you have $$\begin{pmatrix} r_{n} \\ m_n \\ p_n \end{pmatrix} = M \begin{pmatrix} r_{n-1} \\ m_{n-1} \\ p_{n-1} \end{pmatrix} = M^{n} \begin{pmatrix} r_{0} \\ m_{0} \\ p_{0} \end{pmatrix}.$$
So you have to compute $M^n$ for $n \in \Bbb N$. You can [diagonalize $M$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonalize%20%7B%7B1%2C5%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C3%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C5%2C0%7D%7D) for this purpose in order to have a relation of the form $M= SJS^{-1}$. You'll then have $M^n = SJ^nS^{-1}$ and $J^n$ is easy to compute since it is diagonal. Finally computing
$$\begin{pmatrix} r_{n} \\ m_n \\ p_n \end{pmatrix} = SJ^nS^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} r_{0} \\ m_{0} \\ p_{0} \end{pmatrix},$$
will give you a close form for $r_n,m_n,p_n$.

Comment: By the way, note that
$$\begin{pmatrix} r_n \\ m_n \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 5 \\ 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} r_{n-1} \\ m_{n-1} \end{pmatrix}$$
and $p_n = 5m_{n-1}$, but this don't significantly reduce the diagonalization work since it is straightforward to see that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $M$.

Answer (score 0):

It is given that,
$$r_n=r_{n-1}+5m_{n-1}$$ 
$$m_n = r_{n-1} + 3m_{n-1}.$$ 
By subtracting we can obtain that,
$$r_n=m_n+2m_{n-1}$$
$$r_{n-1}=m_{n-1}+2m_{n-2}.$$
Hence
$$m_n=4m_{n-1}+2m_{n-2}.$$
This second order liner recurrence with $m_0=1$ and $m_1=6.$
I think you can solve this one and try to find $r_n$ and $p_n$ via substituting $m_n.$